# Concurrent Update Issue

Tags: java

I have a basic java programming. The question is there are 2 stations who share a same runways, lets make it as station A (SA) and station B (SB). When SA assign an airplane to landing, SB couldn't assign any airplane to landing or departure until SA release it. And once SA landed the runways, it will park on docking station and i assume there is maximum 4 docking station in the airport.
The problem is when i run 2 threads together, once i allow SA to assign an airplane to the runways at the same time SB also allow to assign an airplane to runways too. And after SA's airplane reach the docking station and update the value, also SB reach the docking station, the docking station doesn't update at all. Can anyone please solve my problem?? Thanks. My code will be show on below:

ATC.java

```
package ccsd;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ATC implements Runnable
{
static Process test = new Process();
Process b;
int option;
int currentRunway;
int currentDockSpace;
int airplaneID;

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


 ATC (Process a) {

 b = a;

 }

public void run()
{
    try
    {
            System.out.println("Air Traffic Control");    
            System.out.println("1. Assign airplane to landing.");
            System.out.println("2. Assign airplane to departure.");
            System.out.println("Enter the option: ");
            option = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
            if (option == 1){
                currentRunway = b.getCurrentRunway();
                currentDockSpace = b.getDockSpace();
                if (currentRunway == 0 && currentDockSpace < 5){
                    currentRunway = 1;
                    b.setCurrentRunway(currentRunway);
                    System.out.println("Input airplane id: ");
                    airplaneID = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                    b.setAirplaneID(airplaneID);
                    System.out.println("Currently airplane "+ b.getAirplaneID() + "is going land.");
                    System.out.println("Processing in... 10.. \n9..\n8..\n7..\n6..\n5..\n4..\n3..\n2..\n1.."); 
                    System.out.println("Airplane" + b.getAirplaneID() + " had been landed.");
                    b.dockIn();
                    b.setCurrentRunway(0);
                    System.out.println("Currently the run way is clear now and "+ b.getDockSpace() + " docking space used.");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Currently there is an airplane landing or lack docking space, please try again later."); 
                    run();
            }

            else if (option == 2){
                currentDockSpace = b.getDockSpace();
                if (currentDockSpace>0){
                System.out.println("Input airplane id: ");
                airplaneID = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                b.setAirplaneID(airplaneID);
                currentRunway = b.getCurrentRunway();
                    if (currentRunway == 0){
                        b.setCurrentRunway(1);       
                        System.out.println("Currently airplane "+ b.getAirplaneID() + "is departuring.");
                        System.out.println("Processing in... 10.. \n9..\n8..\n7..\n6..\n5..\n4..\n3..\n2..\n1.."); 
                        System.out.println("Airplane" + b.getAirplaneID() + " had been departured.");
                        b.dockOut();
                        b.setCurrentRunway(0);
                        System.out.println("Currently the run way is clear now and "+ b.getDockSpace() + " docking space used.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Currently there is an airplane landing, please try again later.");
                        run();
                    }
              }
              else
                {
              System.out.println("Currently there is no any airplane in the docking, please try again later.");
              run();      
            }
    }        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ATC(test));

    thread1.start();

}
```

}

---

ATC2.java

```
package ccsd;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ATC2 implements Runnable
{
Process b;
int option;
int currentRunway;
int currentDockSpace;
int airplaneID;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


 ATC2 (Process a) {

 b = a;

 }

public void run()
{
    try
    {
            System.out.println("Air Traffic Control");    
            System.out.println("1. Assign airplane to landing.");
            System.out.println("2. Assign airplane to departure.");
            System.out.println("Enter the option: ");
            option = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
            if (option == 1){
                currentRunway = b.getCurrentRunway();
                currentDockSpace = b.getDockSpace();
                if (currentRunway == 0 && currentDockSpace < 5){
                    b.setCurrentRunway(1);
                    System.out.println("Input airplane id: ");
                    airplaneID = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                    b.setAirplaneID(airplaneID);
                    System.out.println("Currently airplane "+ b.getAirplaneID() + "is going land.");
                    System.out.println("Processing in... 10.. \n9..\n8..\n7..\n6..\n5..\n4..\n3..\n2..\n1.."); 
                    System.out.println("Airplane" + b.getAirplaneID() + " had been landed.");
                    b.dockIn();
                    b.setCurrentRunway(0);
                    System.out.println("Currently the run way is clear now and "+ b.getDockSpace() + " docking space used.");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Currently there is an airplane landing or lack docking space, please try again later."); 
                    run();
            }

            else if (option == 2){
                currentDockSpace = b.getDockSpace();
                if (currentDockSpace>0){
                System.out.println("Input airplane id: ");
                airplaneID = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
                b.setAirplaneID(airplaneID);
                currentRunway = b.getCurrentRunway();
                    if (currentRunway == 0){
                        b.setCurrentRunway(1);       
                        System.out.println("Currently airplane "+ b.getAirplaneID() + "is departuring.");
                        System.out.println("Processing in... 10.. \n9..\n8..\n7..\n6..\n5..\n4..\n3..\n2..\n1.."); 
                        System.out.println("Airplane" + b.getAirplaneID() + " had been departured.");
                        b.dockOut();
                        b.setCurrentRunway(0);
                        System.out.println("Currently the run way is clear now and "+ b.getDockSpace() + " docking space used.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Currently there is an airplane landing, please try again later.");
                        run();
                    }
              }
              else
                {
              System.out.println("Currently there is no any airplane in the docking, please try again later.");
              run();      
            }
    }        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ATC2(ATC.test));

    thread2.start();

}
```

}

---

```
Process.java

package ccsd;

public class Process {
int airplaneID;
int currentRunway;
int dock;

   public synchronized void setAirplaneID(int airplaneID)
   {
this.airplaneID = airplaneID;       
   }

   public int getAirplaneID()
   {
    return airplaneID;
   }

   public synchronized void setCurrentRunway(int currentRunway)
   {
this.currentRunway = currentRunway;
   }

    public int getCurrentRunway()
    {
    return currentRunway;
    }

    public synchronized void dockIn()
    {
    dock++;
    }

    public synchronized void dockOut()
    {
    dock--;
    }

    public int getDockSpace()
    {
    return dock;
    }

}
```

I hope anyone will tell me step by step what should i do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities for how to represent the runway limitations.

I personally like Queues for lots of things - they seem to fit my mindset.  I've never used a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) but, from the JavaDocs, it might be just what you want.

You could also use an [ArrayBockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) with a capacity of 1.

YMMV.  I bet you'll get a lot of other options.

Comment: Sir can you tell me how exactly to do for my problem please??

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize over multiple threads. Best thing is to use a counting semaphore (java.util.concurrent.Semaphore) for each runway. Maybe even for each docking station as well. With this technique you can synchronize as many objects as required with as many processes (threads) as you like.

Comment: Sir can you tell me how exactly to do for my problem please??